# question on the 3-connected graphs

Tags: graph-theory

I have a question: in the Diestel book, page 62, it is written:

Given an edge $e$ in a graph $G$, let us write $G\stackrel{.}{-}e$  for the multigraph obtained from $G-e$ by suppressing any end of $e$ that has degree 2 in $G-e$.

Can someone provide me with an example? I think I got the idea, but  I would like to have a confirmation.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have an example: 
[image]
In the left picture, we have the graph {a,c,b,0} and an edge $e=0a$. Now, in the middle, the graph corresponds to $G-e$ and in the right, the graph corresponds to $G\stackrel{.}{-}$. Am I right?

Comment: Is $G\stackrel{.}{-}$ a minor of $G$?